# Comparing two datasets with different number of records and different order

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I have two datasets in one workbook (Master data and BAZA OLD). The records in each of the two sheets have 11 columns A:K. The Master data worksheet is updated from time to time using Power Query. I would like to compare the new updated data (Master data) with the old data (BAZA OLD) and all mismatching records to be copied and pasted to the worksheet called Output with information in column L "new invoice".
I have found some macro which partially do what I need but the problem is the order of records in the Master data sheet can change once uploaded via Power Query.
Below is the code I currently have.
Public Sub Comparison()

```
Dim dumpSheet, icdSheet, outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim startRow, outputRow, tempDumpRow, tempICDRow, icdRowCount, finishedICDIndex As Integer
Dim finishedICD() As String
Dim isExist As Boolean

'Set sheets
Set dumpSheet = Sheets("BAZA OLD")
Set icdSheet = Sheets("Master data")
Set outputSheet = Sheets("Output")

'Start row of each sheet for data
startRow = 2
outputRow = 2

'Get row count from ICD sheet
icdRowCount = icdSheet.Range("A:K").End(xlDown).Row

'Index
finishedICDIndex = 0

'Re-define array
ReDim finishedICD(0 To icdRowCount - 1)

'Start row
tempDumpRow = startRow

'Here I looped with OR state, you can modify it to AND start if you want
Do While dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow) <> "" And _
    ("D" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("E" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("F" & tempDumpRow) <> "" And _
    ("G" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("H" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("I" & tempDumpRow) <> "" And _
    ("J" & tempDumpRow) <> "" Or dumpSheet.Range("K" & tempDumpRow) <> ""
    
    
    'Reset exist flag
    isExist = False

    'loop all row in ICD sheet
    For tempICDRow = 1 To icdRowCount Step 1

        'If row is not finished for checking.
        If UBound(Filter(finishedICD, tempICDRow)) < 0 Then

            'If all cell are equal
            If dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("A" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("B" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("C" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("D" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("D" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("E" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("E" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("F" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("F" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("G" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("G" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("H" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("H" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("I" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("I" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("I" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("J" & tempICDRow) And _
               dumpSheet.Range("J" & tempDumpRow) = icdSheet.Range("K" & tempICDRow) Then
               
                'Set true to exist flag
                isExist = True

                'Store finished row
                finishedICD(finishedICDIndex) = tempICDRow

                finishedICDIndex = finishedICDIndex + 1

                'exit looping
                Exit For

            End If

        End If

    Next tempICDRow

    'Show result
    outputSheet.Range("A" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("A" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("B" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("B" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("C" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("C" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("D" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("E" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("E" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("F" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("F" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("G" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("G" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("H" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("H" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("I" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("I" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("J" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("J" & tempDumpRow)
    outputSheet.Range("K" & outputRow) = dumpSheet.Range("K" & tempDumpRow)

    If isExist Then
        outputSheet.Range("L" & outputRow) = ""
    Else
        outputSheet.Range("L" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""BAZA OLD"" but not in ""Saldeo"""
    End If

    'increase output row
    outputRow = outputRow + 1

    'go next row
    tempDumpRow = tempDumpRow + 1

Loop

'loop all row in ICD sheet
For tempICDRow = 1 To icdRowCount Step 1

    'If row is not finished for checking.
    If UBound(Filter(finishedICD, tempICDRow)) < 0 Then

        'Show result
        outputSheet.Range("A" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("A" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("B" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("B" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("C" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("C" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("D" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("D" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("E" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("E" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("F" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("F" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("G" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("G" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("H" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("H" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("I" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("I" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("J" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("J" & tempICDRow)
        outputSheet.Range("K" & outputRow) = icdSheet.Range("K" & tempICDRow)
        
        'outputSheet.Range("P" & outputRow) = "Item found in ""Baza Faktur Saldeo"" but not in ""BAZA OLD"""
        outputSheet.Range("L" & outputRow) = "NEW INVOICE"


        'increase output row
        outputRow = outputRow + 1

    End If

Next tempICDRow
```

End Sub

Comment: Id there one (or more) columns with values unique to the row like an ID number ?

Comment: Especially since you are already using the tool, you could probably easily write a query in PQ to do this. You could probably do a `Table.Join` with `JoinKind.LeftAnti` (or `.RightAnti`) to pick up the records in one table that are not in the other.  Especially since PQ relies on the column names, and not the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a key string for each row by concatenating the cell values and compare the keys on the 2 sheets using a Dictionary Object

```vb
Sub Comparison()

    Const COL_MATCH = 11
    Const SEP = "~"

    Dim dumpSheet As Worksheet, icdSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, outrow As Long
    
    'Set sheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set dumpSheet = .Sheets("BAZA OLD")
        Set icdSheet = .Sheets("Master data")
        Set outputSheet = .Sheets("Output")
    End With
    
    ' dump sheet
    Dim dict As Object, k as String, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dumpSheet
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            Set rng = .Range("A" & i).Resize(, COL_MATCH) 'A-K
            ar = Application.Transpose(rng)
            k = Join(Application.Transpose(ar), SEP) ' key
            ' check not blank
            If Len(k) >= COL_MATCH Then
                If dict.exists(k) Then
                    MsgBox "Key not unique '" & k & "'", vbCritical, .Name & " Row " & i & " and Row " & dict(k)
                Else
                    dict.Add k, i
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' compare master to dump sheet
    outrow = 2
    With icdSheet
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            Set rng = .Range("A" & i).Resize(, COL_MATCH)
            ar = Application.Transpose(rng) 'A-K
            k = Join(Application.Transpose(ar), SEP) ' key
            If Len(k) >= COL_MATCH And Not dict.exists(k) Then
                outputSheet.Range("A" & outrow).Resize(, COL_MATCH).Value2 = rng.Value2
                outputSheet.Cells(outrow, COL_MATCH + 1) = "new invoice"
                outrow = outrow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' result
    If outrow = 2 Then
        MsgBox "No new invoices", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox outrow - 2 & " new invoices", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The new code works perfectly and save me a lot of time and trouble. I have been working on it for days. Thank very much for your help, I really appreciate it.